# Query function to get last row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a sheet where data is updated daily.

however, the last integer often ends in between row 131 to 133.

how do I run a query function to display the last integer in row 1 column C?

I cannot do a simple `=A131` on C1 because it can be on A133 the next day.

[image: 1]
[image: 1]

images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJAAF.jpg

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What do you mean by the end of integer on line 131 ~ 133? What is the exact purpose of your query? Row 1 column C seems pretty random. In my understanding, you want to write a query that find the last element in each column, but I cannot make sure. You would want to make your question clear to get an answer.

Comment: "you want to write a query that find the last element in each column" yes that's correct.

Comment: Ah, it seems I misunderstood the display part. Yeah it would be simple. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

paste in **C1** cell:

```
=QUERY(A1:A, "offset "&COUNTA(A1:A)-1, 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I interpreted the OPs data differently. As I understand it, Column A is populated (from another source?) with integers in the first 130-odd rows and, thereafter, the cells contain text and a variety of other stuff, possibly including dates but NOT including integers. The OP's goal (as I understand it) is to identify the last row that contains an integer. In any event, the OP's "demo" data includes text and integers which are not addressed by your answer.

Comment: FWIW,  it was only today that I realised that I had previously misunderstood the issue, and edited my own answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of my original code.

The value of the last integer and the row number are output for user information.

The code copes with dates, text, pseudo-value text (37*2), and decimals.

---

```
function so5754079102() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  Logger.log("Last row = "+Alast);
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,Alast,1).getValues();
  for (var i = Alast-1;i>=0;i--){
    Logger.log("i = "+i+", data 1 ="+data[i][0]+", and parse data 1 = "+parseInt(data[i][0], 10));
    if (data[i][0] === parseInt(data[i][0], 10)){
      break; 
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange("D1").setValue(+(i+1));
  sheet.getRange("D2").setValue(data[i][0]);
}
```

---

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]